# create interface to connect external server using php (and execute shell commands)

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have 4 servers for web, dns, mail and database. I wanna to create an interface to remotely connect those servers using server's IP (may be port) and username and password(and later, in next step execute linux/winsows commands such as shutdown/reset server, stop/start IIS, stop/start mail server, ...)

Is it possible or any link to help me?

Comment: possible yes, but extremely time consuming if you want to build something yourself, do the servers have any other interface/panel like cpanel or webmin installed ?

Comment: i'm already using plesk but since there are sanctions on my country, I can't use cpanel/plesk anymore. so I want to make a simple host manager just for my own uses.

Comment: is [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) what I should learn about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ssh module as said by GeoPhoenix. You can try another method using curl. I assume you're using php, so consider following example,

```
function check_dserver_process(){
    if(!$ch)
       $ch = curl_init();


        $options=array( CURLOPT_URL => "http://122.165.212.22:81/mysite/init.php",
                        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1,
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, 
                        CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE =>1,
                        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01;Windows NT 5.0)"
                     );

        curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
        $result=curl_exec($ch);  
        $op=($result===false ? curl_error($ch) : $result);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $op;
}
```

If you call above function it will fetches the output from init.php from the given url. so you can run your own commands from init.php using [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function. Before you start the process in init.php make sure the request came from one of your ip.

Answer (score 1):

sockets are a way to do that using a server-client model but i wouldn't suggest it.
 [SSH](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) is another way to connect securely to the server and execute commands, you can create a CGI script at local computer and manage one server at a time, using forms/buttons etc.. note that you must have openssh-server package if  server-side is using linux distribution.

Comment: SSH2 seems is what i'm looking for but installing it is a headache.